# Save file info that already uploaded with Meteor files

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am using https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files, This package provide a collection of uploaded files via Meteor-Files.

How can I insert a document about the file that is already uploaded and not via Meteor-Files? I want to use Meteor-Files to save file info only not uploading. Because I need to get a generated download link for the file. This is provided by Meteor-Files.

Anyone can help me guide how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please, clarify `How can I insert a document about the file that is already uploaded and not via Meteor-Files?`. Add more info, your question is unclear.

Comment: This is done using addFile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used addFile() function provided by FilesCollection class.

Comment: I'll just leave a reference to the docs: [`.addFile()`](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/addFile), I'm glad it's solved